# Difference between mark and celebrate

Tags: vocabulary

Do we celebrate our struggle or mark it? Like, if we struggled for something for 20 years, we achieved it; after 5 years we are celebrating the achievements. We say:

> Celebrating 5 years of achievement

We cannot say:

> Celebrating 5 years of struggle

If we wish to mention the struggle in the punchline, can we say:

> Marking 5 years of struggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in saying that we only celebrate something good.

If we wish to remember the anniversary of something serious or tragic, we can *mark, commemorate* or *acknowledge* it.

Answer (score 1):

Kate's answer is correct, but you mentioned "punchline", which suggests this is part of a joke.

If you're joking, then it might be funny because people are expecting to hear something positive, but instead there's a negative term. Imagine it's a child's 5th birthday and one of the parents is giving a speech and includes,

> Celebrating five years of struggle

It's a bit dark, but people would laugh.